# How to solve an initial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

For this question, I'm having trouble solving this equation. I'm not sure how to proceed further with the substitution. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

For this question, I'm having trouble solving this initial-value problem. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

$$
\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{{u}^{3/2} + \arctan(t)+2u}{1+t^2}, u(0)=4\\
\frac{du}{dt} = u^{3/2} (\frac{\arctan(t) + 2u^{-1/2}}{1+t^2})
$$
Let $x = u^{-1/2}\,dx = \frac{-1}{2}u^{-3/2} \,du$

Comment: Note $u=\frac{1}{x^2}$ so $\frac{du}{dt}=-\frac{2}{x^3}\frac{dx}{dt}$. Can you proceed from here, knowing what $\frac{du}{dt}$ equals?

Comment: The two forms of the equation are not compatible. Please correct the first equation if indeed it is a Bernoulli equation.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation being
$$u'=\frac{u^{3/2}+2 u+\tan ^{-1}(t)}{1+t^2}$$ consider first the homogeneous equation
$$u'=\frac{u^{3/2}+2 u}{1+t^2}$$ which is separable and leads to
$$\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2+\sqrt{u}}\right)=\tan ^{-1}(t)+C$$ There are potentially two (nasty) solutions for $u$.

Now, I suppose that you need to define the integration factor.